# Passing name of button as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a newbie in JQuery and ajax and I would like to know if it is possible to pass a value in a function as parameter and using that value as a name of the button which was clicked and proceed with the logic so to send to servlet to handle. I am trying to not use javascript as it is page driven. So what I have in javascript is below.

```
 function test(buttonId)
 {                   
        alert(buttonId);
 }
```

The thing is I have a dynamic table which depends on some data I get from the database and as part of the table are some button which I create as I loop through the data and creating the table simultenously. So in one of the rows of my table I have a button with following:

```
<table id="error_data">
    <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>Other Table columns names........</tr>
    <% for(int rank=1 ; rank<data.size();
    rank++) { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="button<%=rank%>" value="Suspend Email" onclick="test('button<%=rank%>')">
        </tr>
        <%}%>
</table>
```

I hope I am not verbose in my question I want to be able to click on some button in one of my rows and only deal with data for that row and not refresh anything besides for that row data only. And I think maybe it possible with combination of ajax and jquery some how as ajax is data driven. Any shed of light is highly appreciated, is it possible to try and achieve what I am trying to do. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If `test` is called from the button click event, the context (`this`) will be the button itself, so you can refer to the button name just by doing `this.name`. Easy, isn't it? ;)

Comment: Your solutions can be improved by using unobtrusive JavaScript, maybe using a library such as jQuery could help you with that.